# Ultilizar mesmo componente em JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing

Antes de descrever o problema em si, vou explicitar o que eu estou tentando fazer.

Eu vou precisar utilizar alguns botões que vão fazer basicamente a mesma coisa, só que as ações que eles vão aplicar mudam de uma aba `(JTabbedPane)` para outra. Então, pensei que se eu usasse o mesmo componente eu economizaria código, além de ser mais orientado, não tenho certeza se o que eu tentei fazer é correto, aceito sugestões em relação a isso.

Tenho dois problemas:

1º: eu adiciono o mesmo componente em abas diferentes, e toda vez que adiciono eu instancio eles (pensei que seria o certo a se fazer). O que acontece é que as ações não estão ocorrendo corretamente como eu defini.

2º: eu defini que as abas e os botões dentro das abas devem ser habilitados (enable) e desabilitados (disable) quando clicar nos botões de cima (habilitar e desabilitar), porém ele não esta fazendo isso pra todos.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class NewClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private JPanel painelBotao = new JPanel();
    private JButton habilita = new JButton("Habilitar");
    private JButton desabilita = new JButton("Desabilitar");
    private JButton botao01 = new JButton();
    private JButton botao02 = new JButton();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass n = new NewClass();
        n.setVisible(true);
    }

    public NewClass() {
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();

        jp.add(habilita);
        jp.add(desabilita);
        botaoHabilita();
        botaoDesabilita();

        tabbedPane.addTab("Aba 01", aba01());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Aba 02", aba02());
        tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.BEFORE_LINE_BEGINS);
        jp.add(tabbedPane);
        add(jp);
        botaoAba01();
        botaoAba02();
        habilita(false);
        setSize(500, 320);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JComponent aba01() {
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();

        adicionaBotaoItem(botao01 = new JButton("Botão 1"));
        jp.add(painelBotao = new JPanel());

        adicionaBotaoItem(botao02 = new JButton("Botão 2"));
        jp.add(painelBotao = new JPanel());
        return jp;
    }

    public JComponent aba02() {
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();

        adicionaBotaoItem(botao01 = new JButton("Botão 1"));
        jp.add(painelBotao = new JPanel());

        adicionaBotaoItem(botao02 = new JButton("Botão 2"));
        jp.add(painelBotao = new JPanel());
        return jp;
    }

    private void adicionaBotaoItem(JButton botao) {
        painelBotao.add(botao);
        botao.addActionListener(this);
        painelBotao.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    public void botaoAba01() {
        botao01.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Botão 01 - aba 01");
            }
        });

        botao02.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Botão 02 - aba 01");
            }
        });
    }

    public void botaoAba02() {
        botao01.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Botão 01 - aba 02");
            }
        });

        botao02.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Botão 02 - aba 02");
            }
        });
    }

    public void botaoHabilita() {
        habilita.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                habilita(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void botaoDesabilita() {
        habilita.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                habilita(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public void habilita(boolean status) {
        tabbedPane.setEnabled(status);
        botao01.setEnabled(status);
        botao02.setEnabled(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer "reciclar" botões entre abas, mas em cada aba eles terão ações diferentes, é ISSO?

Comment: @diegofm pode - se dizer que é isso, porém eu não tenho certeza se deveria fazer isso, eu so comecei a fazer assim porque eu achei que estava repetindo código demais

Comment: Qual a função desses botões? Tá meio confuso o código. O que você pretende com cada um deles?

Comment: @diegofm ai so fiz um exemplo simples, mais na real eles vão incluir e excluir linhas de uma tabela, cada aba tem uma tabela diferente. Eu deveria criar botoes diferentes pra cada aba ?

Comment: Então não é uma boa reaproveitar botões neste caso.

Comment: ok, era uma duvida fazer isso ou não. No caso, eu apago o post ? ou edito ele ?

Comment: Não, acho que da pra sugerir algo. Vo tentar responder com uma ideia que tive. Só não sei se ela vai se encaixar com essa nova informação de tabela. Seria interessante voce até editar a pergunta com essa situação das tabelas também, aí já mata o problema de vez.